# CSS, JS and images are not loading while sharing WAMP over local network

Tags: apache-2.2, network-share, local-area-network, share

I have share my wamp over my personal LAN . (Server IP : 192.168.0.100)

When I am trying to access wamp server it's working perfectly. But when I open website hosted on server using client machine (192.168.0.103) , it doesn't load CSS - Images and JS files. So  I saw console and found that my browser is trying to load :

> localhost//mysite/css/style.css

And failing to load resource. now when I try to load the same resource directly from browser using

> 192.168.0.100/mysite/css/style.css

It's showing me css file ! Now I am confused how to solve this problem so that my browser load that css perfectly !

Please help me ! thanks in advance !

Comment: If it solved your issue, why are u removing answer mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its working just as it should. If the browser reads some include directive with "localhost" it tries to look up that file in your current computer ( if localhost is set to 127.0.0.1, and default it is ). So **you should change the path of those files in your html**, to a relative url, like: `css/style.css`. This will work if that html page is in that directory where the `css/style.css` can be found.

Comment: Yeah.. thanks I found and fixed that issue.. thank you so much !!